# How to create this kinda halftone circle in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, halftone

I'm trying to create this halftone effect in Inkscape but I'm not able to produce it. All I'm able to do is create a small circle and clone it to produce simple halftone. But how do I do this?

[image: Circular halftone effect]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To quickly create the desired image we can use the ***Clone > Create Tiled Clones...*** tool.

Here is the steps involved (in *Symmetry: **P1:** simple translation* mode):

1. Draw a **circle** of desired size (e.g. 400 px)
2. Set fill to nothing
3. Set Stroke

   - ***Paint*** to fully transparent (here I used light blue for demonstration
   - ***Style*** to *Mid Marker* **`DotL`** (dot size depends on stroke width!)

   [image]
4. Choose ***Clone > Create tiled clone*** with the following settings:

   - Rows, Columns `1 x 10` (for 10 clones)
   - Shift x: `-100%` (to keep clones centered)
   - Rotation per columns `10°`

   [image]
5. **Select all** or create a group.
6. Choose ***Clone > Create tiled clone*** with the following settings:

   - Rows, Columns `1 x 10`
   - Shift x: `-100%`
   - Scale X (per column): `-10%`
   - Scale Y (per column): `-10%`

   [image]

By choosing different settings we may change number or color of dots, rotation, or introduce a fade effect if needed.

- For changing colors of the dots we have to apply *Extensions > Modify Path > Color Markers to match Stroke* in step 1. above **before** we make the stroke transparent.
- Additionally in the next example a **Fade Out** of `10 %` in *Blur & Opacity* and a rotation of `5°` was added when creating the clones in step 6.

  [image]

Comment: Nice, this makes much more sense than my answer

Comment: @JohnB Not really, because with your approach you are much more free to do things other than black dots.

Comment: This seems better. I'm doing this right now. And I'm unable to get the step 4 working correctly. Here's how I see after performing 4th step https://i.imgur.com/d3isGnB.png

Comment: Okay, it was solved by selecting all and aligning them to the center (horizontally & vertically). But now, how do I change the color of the circles? Or how do I add circular gradient to them so that they appear faded as the circles go deeper? Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: I'm able to do that fade out one but unable to change the color. When I select the halftone circle and click Extensions > Modify Path > Color Markers, nothing happens. Am I doing it wrong? I've even tried changing the stroke color but the entire circle's color changes to the same color then.

Comment: Deciding on the color is the first step actually. It's in the stroke color before you do dots or clones. Only then the dot will get the stroke color on *Color Markers to match Stroke*. Then we can change the stroke to invisible (or else). All cloned dots will then have the initial color (which unfortunately can't be changed other than fade later).

Comment: One last question. I'm still not able to change the color of the halftone. Could you please explain in detail? You're explaining it correctly but I've problem understanding it since I don't do it regularly. Please?

Comment: 1. Draw circle - 2. define stroke paint with the color you need 3. define mid markers DotL 4. *Extensions > Modify Path > Color Markers to match Stroke* to make dots the color of the stroke 5. Define stroke color `A` (opacity) to `0` to make it invisible 6. proceed with 4. in answer above. The "fade" effect will add transparency to the color.

Comment: Seriously man. Love you. Love the way you explain. Thanks a lot for your precious time.

Answer (score 2):

<s>This would be easier with Illustrator's Transform Effect, but with Inkscape I believe you can only emulate that by combining Duplicate and Transform.</s>

You can create rings of dots by using a rotation transform. Offset the center of rotation of a dot, duplicate it, and apply a Rotation Transform. The angle of rotation will be defined by the number of desired dots in the circle divided by 360.

You can use the same technique to quickly create multiple rings. This is not quite exactly the same as your posted graphic because it will result in the same number of dots per ring, but this will help illustrate how to use transform and duplicate together:

Start with a ring like this, select it:

[image: Inkscape screenshot]

Duplicate it via <kbd>Edit → Duplicate</kbd> or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Apply a Scale Transform via <kbd>Object → Transform</kbd>

[image: Inkscape screenshot]

Repeat until happy:

[image: Inkscape screenshot]

Comment: That'd be too tedious. Anyway, thanks for this one. Is there any other way to do it?