# Create clock pattern with 12 "blocks" in Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape

I have already a vector path in Inkscape but it contains 15 "blocks" or "segments", like so:

[image]

I did not create this image and I don't know how to modify it to give it sense as the background of a clock. What I want is to have the segments reduced to 12 and align them to the clock hands. This way, it will be easier to tell the time based on which segment the hand is pointing to.

Any ideas on how to modify this or to easily create a new one?

Comment: Redraw the patterns, copy the shape, then rotate every copy

Comment: I'd go for 11 tiled clones of each segment with a rotation angle of 30° - see http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28309/how-to-create-this-kinda-halftone-circle-in-inkscape

Comment: See also [http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26679/how-to-create-these-rotated-clones](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26679/how-to-create-these-rotated-clones).

Comment: I would do it from scratch, with multiple, concentric rings and and an overlay of one such ring with an 12 arm star.

Answer (score 1):

The commenters have said it all. Here it is, step by step:

[image]

1. In a new Inkscape file, **import the original raster image** from above. It's a bit distorted, so set its size to **400x400 pixels** (making it square and ensuring that we can draw symmetric circles on top of it).
2. **Draw three circles** on top of the rings with no fill and stroke widths of **10**, **8** and **7** pixels, respectively (*red*). **Draw a circle** with no stroke and some fill in the middle, so that it just overlaps the inner ring (*green*). Finally, **draw a rectangle** with a height similar to that of one of the spokes in the original and a width that overlaps the outer ring on both sides (*blue*). **Select all objects and align them** (`Shift+Ctrl+A`) vertically and horizontally with respect to the original image.
3. **Subtract the filled circle from the rectangle**. To do this, ensure the circle is on top (select it and press `Home` or do "Object" > "Raise to top"), then select both the circle and the rectangle. Now do "Path" > "Difference". This leaves an object that has a spoke on either side.
4. **Duplicate and rotate the spokes**. To do that, bring up the "Transform menu" (`Shift+Ctrl+M`) go to the tab "Rotate" and enter **30** in the "Angle" field. Now select the spoke object (*blue*), duplicate it (`Ctrl+D`) and hit "Apply" in the "Transform" menu. Repeat this four times (until the circle is filled with spokes).
5. **Join everything**. Select all objects and convert them to paths, by doing "Path" > "Stroke to Path". Then do "Path" > "Union". Finally use the "Dropper" from the toolbar on the left to pick the teal fill color from the original.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Could also create the basic 3-line shape, turn it into a brush pattern and adjust the settings until you have 12 in a circle.[image]